# Vaadin Flow DateTimePicker dirty inside CRUD

Tags: vaadin, crud, datetimepicker, vaadin-flow

I am adding a `com.vaadin.flow.component.datetimepicker.DateTimePicker` to a `com.vaadin.flow.component.crud.Crud`. This appears to always mark the CRUD dirty. I noticed that things are all good when using a `com.vaadin.flow.component.datepicker.DatePicker`. This problem only shows for `DateTimePicker`. How should I cope with this?

```
DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker("When");
dtp.setStep(Duration.ofMillis(1));
// ...
binder.bind(dtp, new ValueProvider<MyEvent, LocalDateTime>() {
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime apply(final MyEvent source) {
        return source.getWhen();
    }
}, ...
```

So, `DateTimePicker` with millis step, provided with a `LocalDateTime` value.

Later Edit:
I have looked further into the `DateTimePicker.setPresentationValue(LocalDateTime)` implementation and found that some JavaScript is being executed:

```
datePicker.getElement().executeJs("this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', { bubbles: true }));");
```

Could this be it? Unfortunately, I am not familiar to Vaadin's internals, so unsure why is that required there.

Comment: Which version of Vaadin are you using? Because the DateTimePicker had some packages in the most recent version

Comment: Using Vaadin 14.7.0

Comment: Can you please try it with 14.7.2?

Comment: Yes, I did switch to `<vaadin.version>14.7.2</vaadin.version>` in my `pom.xml`, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced the same behavior on other components as well (e.g.: [EnhancedDateTimePicker](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/enhanceddatetimepicker) and [Autocomplete](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/autocomplete)). In some situation there is a ValueChangeEvent that is fired from the client even if the value is not changed at all. This makes the field dirty and using binder this produces that `binder.hasChanges()` returns true.

I have made a workaround creating a custom component that contains two instances of the component. One is hidden (not visible) and gets updated only when the value of the visible one actually changes. From the binder (and any other external) perspective, it is the hidden component that provides value and events.

Here it is for the EnhancedDateTimePicker:

```
public class DateTimeSelection extends HorizontalLayout implements 
        HasValue<AbstractField.ComponentValueChangeEvent<EnhancedDateTimePicker, LocalDateTime>, LocalDateTime> {

    private EnhancedDateTimeField hiddenDateTimeField = new EnhancedDateTimeField("");
    private EnhancedDateTimeField visibleDateTimeField = new EnhancedDateTimeField("");

    public DateTimeSelection() {
        visibleDateTimeField.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
            if (!ObjUtils.eq(event.getValue(), hiddenDateTimeField.getValue())) {
                hiddenDateTimeField.setValue(event.getValue());
            }
        });
        visibleDateTimeField.setWidthFull();
        add(visibleDateTimeField);
    }

    public DateTimeSelection(String label) {
        this();
        setLabel(label);
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return visibleDateTimeField.getLabel();
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        visibleDateTimeField.setLabel(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        hiddenDateTimeField.setValue(localDateTime);
        visibleDateTimeField.setValue(localDateTime);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime getValue() {
        return hiddenDateTimeField.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime getEmptyValue() {
        return hiddenDateTimeField.getEmptyValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<LocalDateTime> getOptionalValue() {
        return hiddenDateTimeField.getOptionalValue();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return hiddenDateTimeField.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        hiddenDateTimeField.clear();
        visibleDateTimeField.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void setReadOnly(boolean b) {
        visibleDateTimeField.setReadOnly(b);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadOnly() {
        return visibleDateTimeField.isReadOnly();
    }

    @Override
    public void setRequiredIndicatorVisible(boolean b) {
        visibleDateTimeField.setRequiredIndicatorVisible(b);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRequiredIndicatorVisible() {
        return visibleDateTimeField.isRequiredIndicatorVisible();
    }

    @Override
    public Registration addValueChangeListener(ValueChangeListener<? super AbstractField.ComponentValueChangeEvent<EnhancedDateTimePicker, LocalDateTime>> valueChangeListener) {
        return hiddenDateTimeField.addValueChangeListener(valueChangeListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, CT Liv! I thought that Vaadin's major versions are (more) mature, but as I explore it I realize that it's not the case. I don't understand why are we having Vaadin Flow 21 and now 22 (alpha), when 14 is missing lots of basic functionality and requires dirty fixes every here and there. I find myself more and more in the position to consider using Vaadin 8 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1043 . You should be able to change your project's pom.xml to pick-up the v 14.7.1 version of the timepicker flow component with the appropriate fix.